# Python: Using a Cookie to Maintain State

Tags: python, http, post, cookies

I've set up a system to practice making a Padding Oracle attack and after much work I've discovered that my exploit isn't working because my code isn't maintaining state with a cookie! After reading up on cookies I could still use a little help on modifying my code so it properly maintains state.

I start off by making my cookie jar. This should also grab the cookie from the site I want (to my understanding):

```
cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))
opener.open('http://192.168.1.12/main_login.php')
```

I have normal working code that grabs the website data so I can parse it through BeautifulSoup

```
usock = urllib2.urlopen("http://192.168.1.12/main_login.php")   
data = usock.read()
usock.close()
```

And sends the post with the appropriate data:

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.3/check_login.php'
values = {'login_captcha': CAPTCHAguess, 'captchaID': BogusCipher, 'iv': IVprime}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
response.close()
```

What do I need to change in the above two bits of code so that it will use the cookie to maintain state when pulling and POSTing the data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same opener for all requests for this to work. So instead of:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

use:

```
response = opener.open(req)
```

Mandatory note in these cases: consider using the excellent [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) library